# Elemento adicionado com jquery append não dispara evento

Tags: jquery

Clonei uma div que contém 2 elementos: checkbox e button.
Os elementos na div principal, de origem, dispara os eventos normalmente.

Acontece que, após clonar a div com os elementos dentro, os elementos criados não disparam nenhum evento. Tentei de várias formas e não funcionou.

[Teste com parte do meu código real no JSFiddle, não funciona](http://jsfiddle.net/xmdenis/666bnqfx/3/)

[Teste com um código que criei do zero para testar no JSFiddle, funciona](http://jsfiddle.net/xmdenis/666bnqfx/2/)

Não consigo idenficar o porque não funciona no meu código real. Será que podem me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que o código gera um novo elemento `.status` que não havia antes, do qual esse botão `.nova_subdemanda` é descendente.

Apesar de já estares a usar delegação de eventos tens de mudar `$('.status').on(...` para `$(document).on(...` ou:

```
$('#lista_status').on('click','.nova_subdemanda', function(event){
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/666bnqfx/4/

Comment: Vi lá e o botão de adicionar nova subdemanda (.nova_subdemanda) funciona. Mas ao fazer o mesmo com o elemento checkbox ele se comporta de forma inesperada. Ele esconde ou mostra a lista de subdemandas do primeiro status. Você notou isso?

Comment: Ah! Esquece! Bobeei aqui. O que vai ser executado depois do evento eu ajeito aqui. Obrigado! Perfeito! Tinha tentado um tanto de coisa, menos isso. ;)